# pywintypes.com_error: (-1, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'TSTestModule::TestVariant', 'Given variant identifier is not declared in the XML test module!')

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, canoe

I would like to change the TestVariant in testmodule using python and I'm trying to execute below function:

```
def test_env(self):
        self.test_Module_envr = self.app.test_Module_envr
        print('TestEnv Name:',self.test_Module_envr.Name, ", Enabled:",self.test_Module_envr.Enabled)

        self.test_modules = Dispatch(self.test_Module_envr)
        for i, test in enumerate(self.test_modules.TestModules, start=1):
            name = os.path.basename(test.FullName)
            test_module=Dispatch(test)
            print('\n'+'-'*90)
            print(f"{i}. TestModule: {os.path.splitext(name)[0]} Name: {test.Name} Enabled: {test.Enabled} Variant: {test_module.TestVariant} \n")
            #selection of Variant
            test_module.TestVariant = 'test_1'
```

while assigning the required TestVariant, it is showing the following error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'TSTestModule::TestVariant', 'Given variant identifier is not declared in the XML test module!', 'C:\\Program Files\\Vector CANoe 16\\Exec64\\CANoe64.chm', 17254, -2147467259), None)
```

I tried to access the TestVariant in the test module, while assigning the required TestVariant, it is showing the following error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'TSTestModule::TestVariant', 'Given variant identifier is not declared in the XML test module!', 'C:\\Program Files\\Vector CANoe 16\\Exec64\\CANoe64.chm', 17254, -2147467259), None)
```

I would like change it to required TestVariant using above function.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a TestVariant called `test_1` for all test modules?

Comment: Yes, it's there in the XML Test module.
Even giving the same or current TestVariant, it is giving the same error.
Eg: "test_module.TestVariant = test_module.TestVariant"

Comment: Could you add the `variants` block from the XML to the question?

Comment: <variants>

    <variant name="test_1">test_1</variant>

    <variant name="test_2">test_2</variant>

    <variant name="test_3">test_3</variant>

    <variant name="test_4">test_4</variant>

  </variants>

Comment: Looks good to me. Would make sense to contact Vector support instead.